# How to get specific values of each field using php DOM Script ? for the below format?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I want to get the value of each field like "Delhi" , "Kolkatta".

How can i do this using php DOM Script ?

here is the source of the page to parsed.

```
<tbody><tr>
<td>Delhi</td>
<td>66.91</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Kolkata</td>
<td>69.52</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mumbai</td>
<td>78.44</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Chennai</td>
<td>69.93</td>
</tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` to achieve desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/813061)

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//tbody/tr/td");
$data=array();
for($x=0;$x<$results->length;$x+=2)
{
    $instance=$results->item($x);
    if($instance instanceof DOMElement)
    {
        $data[]=$results->item($x)->textContent;
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

See question here: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

> How to use the DOM extension has been covered extensively on StackOverflow, so if you choose to use it, you can be sure most of the issues you run into can be solved by searching/browsing Stack Overflow

Here an example:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<tbody><tr>
<td>Delhi</td>
<td>66.91</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Kolkata</td>
<td>69.52</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mumbai</td>
<td>78.44</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Chennai</td>
<td>69.93</td>
</tr></tbody>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$data = [];
foreach($elements as $node) {
    $childElements = $node->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $data[$childElements->item(0)->nodeValue] = $childElements->item(1)->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `simplexml` function, **please someone correct me if it is wrong way or bad idea**

```
$xml='<tbody><tr>
<td>Delhi</td>
<td>66.91</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Kolkata</td>
<td>69.52</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mumbai</td>
<td>78.44</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Chennai</td>
<td>69.93</td>
</tr></tbody> ';
echo "<pre>";
$arr=simplexml_load_string($xml);
$arr_new=array();
$arr1=json_decode(json_encode((array)$arr), TRUE);
foreach($arr1 as $val){
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
        $arr_new[$val[$k]['td'][0]]=$val[$k]['td'][1];
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Delhi] => 66.91
    [Kolkata] => 69.52
    [Mumbai] => 78.44
    [Chennai] => 69.93
)
```